# Secondary index missing records after migration (add/remove node)

Tags: aerospike, secondary-indexes

I have noticed that whenever i add/remove nodes from my cluster, secondary index query returns empty result for some records even after migration completes. However they can be successfully retrieved using PK. I am using version 3.8.1 with RAM+HDD model. Currently i have to drop and create each secondary index manually every time. Is there better solution available for this?

Comment: Nishant, Does the query error out or returns "OK" without any result. Which version of OS are you runnnig it against. And how many nodes in the cluster ? - R

Comment: @DBGuy Yes it returned OK with few records (less than eligible records). I am using CentOS 6.6. i have 8 nodes in my cluster.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely hitting the following bug:

[AER-4930] - (SINDEX) Replica-creates not updating sindex entry, cause missing records in query.

This got addressed in version 3.9.0.1: http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.9.0.1